Should I maximize my roof for solar panels?
I’m planning to install a solar PV system on my house. I have a gable roof (south-north facing) with a 44° tilt and no shading issues. I'm thinking of installing 18 modules on the south side, which would be Suntech 440W (full black, bifacial, glass-glass) panels, recommended by the installer. That would give me a total of 7.92kWp.
I can choose my own inverter and am leaning towards a hybrid model. We’ve roughly estimated our electricity consumption to be under 7000kWh per year (including charging an electric car). I’m not planning to install a battery storage system right away, but maybe in the future.
I have space for 6-8 additional panels, which would cost me €220 per panel (materials + installation).
Would it be worth it to install the extra panels and maximize the roof space? Or should I stick with the original plan?

It depends on many factors. I think you should calculate the energy demand per week, e.g. one week in winter, and one in summer, and check how much the panel would produce.
In winter you should have much less energy, but you may use more electricity (lighting, possibly cooking with oven and other hot stuffs). So extra panel may help. But if your consumption is toward summer (air conditioning, more showers) things may be different. And if you are near of between the tropics, production patterns are better.
Also check if now or in future may be possible to sell excess electricity to the power grid.
Too many parameters. OTOH adding extra panels is cheap now (because base costs are already included). Later it will more complex.

There are two viewpoints to this question.
Firstly, if your goal is self-sufficiency (and in that case you should install the batteries too even if it doesn't make financial sense), install all the panels you can. You need them during the winter. Otherwise you are reliant on the grid.
Secondly, if the goal is financial profit, there are three options:

Solar power is so expensive it doesn't make sense to install any panels at all
Solar power for self-use is cheaper than grid electricity because you don't have to pay taxes and transmission fee, but solar power for selling to the grid is more expensive than what revenue you get: in this case you should optimize the amount of panels you have based on how much energy you can use yourself
Solar power is so cheap selling it to grid makes sense: in this case you should maximize the amount of panels to install, so YES, if this is the case, install the extra panels too.

I believe these days region (1) doesn't apply at all in any case. Whether region (2) or (3) is true in your case depends on the average price of electricity you see when selling solar power to the grid, the cost of the solar panels, and the cost of installation.

The other thing to add to this is if the local government is offering rebates for installing solar cells, such schemes usually operate for limited periods & by getting the extra cells now one gets the rebate for all the installed cells. If one opts to install the extra later, the rebate system may no longer apply & the home owner then has to pay full cost for the extra cells later on.

Regarding batteries, if one is still partially reliant on the grid for electricity & if the installed battery capacity is sufficient, batteries can prevent individual homes from experiencing power black outs.

There is no clear answer based on data provided, so keep these things in mind when deciding:

solar PV efficiency is improving with time, both in power generation (perovskite) and reliability (longer life)
cost to permit and design subsequent addition; might be cheaper to install it all now
rebates come and go, current ones might be the last, or the next one could be better
your energy provider may enable a 'virtual battery' offering, where extra capacity you generate is available to you when needed (not just at time of generation)
loads of large appliances are getting electrified - consider geothermal application for extra power you're generating

